# Is it possible to store a Rust struct containing a closure in a different struct?

Tags: rust, traits

The [Crius](https://github.com/reneweb/crius) library provides
circuit-breaker-like functionality for Rust. Crius defines a struct called [`Command`](https://docs.rs/crius/0.3.1/crius/command/struct.Command.html) which looks like this:

```
pub struct Command<P, T, CMD>
where
    T: Send,
    CMD: Fn(P) -> Result<T, Box<CommandError>> + Sync + Send,
{
    pub config: Option<Config>,
    pub cmd: CMD,
    phantom_data: PhantomData<P>,
}
```

Is it possible to store an instance of `Command` as a field in a different struct?

I started out trying to return a value of this type from a
function. Simply instantiating the type is no problem:

```
/// This function constructs a simple instance of `Command<P, T, CMD>` with the
/// types set to:
///
///     P ~ u8
///     T ~ u8
///     CMD: Fn(u8) -> Result<u8, Box<CommandError>> + Send + Sync
///
/// This function compiles fine. However, there is no *concrete* type
/// for `CMD`. In compiler output it will be referred to as an
/// "anonymous" type looking like this:
///
///    Command<u8, u8, [closure@src/lib.rs:19:21: 19:38]>
fn simple_command_instance() {
    let _ = Command::define(|n: u8| Ok(n * 2));
}
```

It becomes more difficult when writing a return type for the
function:

```
fn return_command_instance() -> Command<u8, u8, ???> {
                                                ^
                                                |
                          What goes here? -------

    Command::define(|n: u8| Ok(n * 2))
}
```

The type inferred by the compiler is anonymous - it can't be put in
there. Many times when closures are passed around, people resort to
using a `Box<F: Fn<...>>`, however there is no implementation for
`impl Fn<T> for Box<Fn<T>>` - so boxing the type breaks the
constraints given by `crius::command::Command`.

In versions of Rust that have the new `impl Trait` feature (such as the
upcoming stable release), this is possible:

```
/// Use new `impl Trait` syntax as a type parameter in the return
/// type:
fn impl_trait_type_param() -> Command<u8, u8, impl Fn(u8) -> Result<u8, Box<CommandError>>> {
    Command::define(|n: u8| Ok(n * 2))
}
```

This does not work in stable Rust and `impl Trait` can only
be used in return types, not in struct members.

Trying to propagate the generic type ends up looking something like
this:

```
fn return_cmd_struct<F>() -> Command<u8, u8, F>
where
    F: Fn(u8) -> Result<u8, Box<CommandError>> + Send + Sync,
{
    Command::define(|n: u8| Ok(n * 2))
}
```

But this does not compile:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:33:21
   |
33 |     Command::define(|n: u8| Ok(n * 2))
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found closure
   |
   = note: expected type `F`
              found type `[closure@src/lib.rs:33:21: 33:38]`
```

Again, I don't know of a way to specify that concrete type in the
result signature.

---

Even if propagating the type as a generic parameter worked, it would
still be an issue for our specific use-case. We want to store a
`Command` as part of an [actix](https://github.com/actix/actix) actor which registers as a
[`SystemService`](https://docs.rs/actix/0.5.6/actix/registry/trait.SystemService.html), which requires a `Default` implementation, which
again eventually forces us to provide a concrete type.

If anyone has any ideas about possible ways to do this, please share
them. Definitely knowing that it *isn't* possible would also be nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I currently know of no way a closure may be used as part of a return type other than using `impl` or `Box`, both of which you have mentioned and cannot be used in this situation.

An alternative would be to use a function pointer instead of a closure, like so:

```
fn return_command_instance() -> Command<u8, u8, fn(u8) -> Result<u8, Box<CommandError>>> {
    Command::define(|n: u8| Ok(n * 2))
}
```

Notice the lower case `fn` to signify a function pointer and not the trait `Fn`. This is explained in more details in the chapter on [Advanced Functions & Closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-05-advanced-functions-and-closures.html#function-pointers).

This will only work if you do not capture any variables in the function, if you do it will be compiled into a closure.

Comment: This seems to have solved my problem, thanks for pointing it out! After a re-read of some `crius` source code I also noticed that it uses the function pointer types internally in some places.